# Auto-value-gson with an interface error, register an InstanceCreator?

Tags: android, interface, gson, auto-value

I have an interface class that looks like this.

```
public interface Species {
    String name();
}
```

And a `Human` class that implements `@AutoValue` with a TypeAdapter.

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class Human implements Parcelable, Species {
    public static Human create(String humanVariable) {
        return new AutoValue_Human(humanVariable);
    }

    public static Human create(String name, String humanVariable) {
        return new AutoValue_Human(name, humanVariable);
    }

    public static TypeAdapter<Human> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
        return new AutoValue_Human.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
    }

    @SerializedName("name")
    public abstract String name();

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("human_variable")
    public abstract String humanVariable();

    @Override
    public String name() {
       return name();
    }
}
```

When I pull down data from our API I get this error.

> Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface ..... Species.
>   Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this
>   problem.

I've been trying to figure out how to handle this but haven't had much luck.

I found some resources like this [Serialize And Deserialize Interfaces](http://technology.finra.org/code/serialize-deserialize-interfaces-in-java.html) but they don't use @AutoValue or auto-value-gson so not sure how to put everything together.

Any help would be much appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

`InstanceCreator` is not often used in Gson, suggested by Gson in such cases making some confusion, and usually can be replaced with type adapters (factories). The `InstanceCreator` interface can only create a default instance that won't be merged with the JSON you're trying to deserialize. For example:

```
{
    "name": "13289/john-doe",
    "human_variable": "John Doe"
}
```

```java
public static Human create() {
    return new AutoValue_Human("anonymous", null);
}
```

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Species.class, (InstanceCreator<Species>) type -> Human.create())
        .create();
```

```java
final Species species = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Species.class);
System.out.println(species.name());
```

Output:

> anonymous

In this case you'd bind the `Species` interface with the default `Human` instance only. According to that, `species.name()` would return `anonymous` only regardless the JSON (Gson internal `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.Adapter` just skips all JSON fields (actually, it collects all fields first against the given field declared type, not an actual object type after the `InstanceCreator`-created instance is created) because it's an interface -- not sure if it's not a bug though).

What you really need here is the following steps:

- Use `com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:...` if you're not using yet.
- Register the `Human` type adapter factory created using the `auto-value-gson` extension.
- Deserialize your JSON as a concrete `Human` instance rather than a `Species` instance.

For example:

```java
@GsonTypeAdapterFactory
abstract class HumanAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    public static TypeAdapterFactory create() {
        return new AutoValueGson_HumanAdapterFactory();
    }

}
```

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(HumanAdapterFactory.create())
        .create();
```

```java
final Human human = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Human.class);
System.out.println(human.name());
System.out.println(human.humanVariable());
```

Output:

> 13289/john-doe
>   John Doe

This is the solution I would recommend the most.

---

If, for any justified reason, you really need to deserialize a JSON as an unknown `Species` instance and resolve its type dynamically, you could create a more complex solution. One of its "classic" solutions is resolving an object type by its special JSON property (inspired by [RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java) coming from the Gson extras, not published as an artifact though):

```
{
    "type": "human",
    "name": "13289/john-doe",
    "human_variable": "John Doe"
}
```

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        // We'll ask Gson for it ourselves
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(HumanAdapterFactory.create())
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new TypeAdapterFactory() {
            @Override
            public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
                // Check whether we can support the given type
                if ( Species.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
                    final TypeAdapterFactory currentTypeAdapterFactory = this;
                    // And get the "original" type adapter
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    final TypeAdapter<Species> delegateTypeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<Species>) gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, typeToken);
                    final TypeAdapter<Species> speciesTypeAdapter = new TypeAdapter<Species>() {
                        // Type tokens can be static since they are immutabe
                        private /*static*/ final TypeToken<Human> humanTypeToken = TypeToken.get(Human.class);
                        // JsonParser seems to be immutable as well
                        private /*static*/ final JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();

                        @Override
                        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Species value)
                                throws IOException {
                            delegateTypeAdapter.write(out, value);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Species read(final JsonReader in)
                                throws IOException {
                            // Caching the current value to a JSON tree
                            final JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(in);
                            final String type = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject()
                                    .getAsJsonPrimitive("type")
                                    .getAsString();
                            final TypeAdapter<? extends Species> typeAdapter;
                            // Now trying to resolve an appropriate type adapter
                            switch ( type ) {
                            case "human":
                                typeAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(currentTypeAdapterFactory, humanTypeToken);
                                break;
                            default:
                                throw new MalformedJsonException("Unknown type: " + type);
                            }
                            // At this point the JsonReader is moved formed due to the previous read, but we have the JSON tree
                            return typeAdapter.fromJsonTree(jsonElement);
                        }
                    }.nullSafe();
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    final TypeAdapter<T> castSpeciesTypeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) speciesTypeAdapter;
                    return castSpeciesTypeAdapter;
                }
                return null;
            }
        })
        .create();
```

```java
final Species species = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Species.class);
System.out.println(species.getClass());
System.out.println(species.name());
```

Output:

> class q43267910.AutoValue_Human
>   13289/john-doe