# Inheritance with Retrofit failed to invoke, with no args

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, auto-value

I have this base abstract class that looks like this.

```
public abstract class Species implements Parcelable {
    public Species() { 

    }

    public abstract String name();
}
```

And then my Human class looks like this.

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class Human extends Species implements Parcelable {
    public static Human create(String humanVariable) {
        return new AutoValue_Human(humanVariable);
    }

    public static Human create(String name, String humanVariable) {
        return new AutoValue_Human(name, humanVariable);
    }

    public static TypeAdapter<Human> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
        return new AutoValue_Human.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
    }

    @SerializedName("name")
    public abstract String name();

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("human_variable")
    public abstract String humanVariable();

}
```

> E/com.service.androidbrain.util.networking.RetrofitCallback.onFailure:
>   Failed to invoke public com.service.example.models.Species() with no
>   args

For some reason however I'm getting this error and I don't understand what is going on, any idea?

Comment: Have you added the `GsonConverterFactory` based on the `Gson` configuration I was suggesting you in your previous question while building the `Retrofit` instance?

Comment: Yeah I have and not sure what is going on, I might be missing something.

Comment: Could you provide the code that builds both Gson and Retrofit instances?

Answer (score 2):

`auto-value-gson` doesn't support the behavior you're trying to achieve.

I assume you declared your retrofit service to return `Call<Species>`, while only `Human.typeAdapter(Gson)` is registered to Gson. This concludes in Gson not knowing of how to acutally create an instance of `Species`.

To make this work, you'd have to (create and) install another type adapter for `Species` which knows how to identify the actual subtype of the species and delegates all model creation to the specific type adapter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you just don't have the `GsonConverterFactory` instantiated correctly. From [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43271823/166589) to your previous question:

```java
@GsonTypeAdapterFactory
abstract class HumanAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    public static TypeAdapterFactory create() {
        return new AutoValueGson_HumanAdapterFactory();
    }

}
```

Therefore the following is unnecessary:

```java
public static TypeAdapter<Human> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
    return new AutoValue_Human.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
}
```

So you just have to instantiate `Gson`:

```java
new GsonBuilder()
        ...
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(HumanAdapterFactory.create())
        .create();
```

*And* configure the Retrofit instance *like* this:

```java
new Retrofit.Builder()
        ...
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)) // THIS is necessary
        .build();
```

*And* make sure your service interface operates on `Human`, *not* `Species`:

```
interface IService {

    @GET("/") // This is probably what you really want
    Call<Human> getHuman();

    @GET("/") // How can you know WHAT the Species is here?
    Call<Species> getSpecies();

}
```

If you really want to go with `getSpecies()`, you MUST know *what* is the real type of the `Species` interface for a particular object: so you either have to use `InstanceCreator` or *detect the real type on some information*. Both of the approaches are described in my answer. In order to make it work:

```
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(HumanAdapterFactory.create())
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new TypeAdapterFactory() {
            @Override
            public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
                // ... that big type adapter here from that answer OR InstanceCreator by it's not useful here
            }
        })
        .create();

final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        ...
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();

final IService service = retrofit.create(IService.class);
final Species species = service.getSpecies()
        .execute()
        .body();
System.out.println(species.getClass());
System.out.println(species.name());
```

That's all you need, but `Call<Human> getHuman();` is the best choice here.

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer composition over inheritance, because at least currently it is not available to do that in `AutoValue`.

See [this issue](https://github.com/google/auto/issues/277) at github.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by removing from my class
the word abstract

Ej
Before

```
    public abstract class Post {
    
    private int userId;
    private int id;
    private String title;
}
```

after

```
public class Post {
    
    private int userId;
    private int id;
    private String title;
}
```